# Interpolating time series in Pandas using Cubic spline

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to fill gaps in a column in my DataFrame using a cubic spline. If I were to export to a list then I could use the numpy's `interp1d` function and apply this to the missing values.

Is there a way to use this function inside pandas?

Comment: I'm surprised you accepted the answer so fast (no offense, hayden ;) because I thought you especially wanted to interpolate time series, but I guess you didn't mean exactly pandas.TimeSeries. I am interested in exactly these topics as well, currently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941472/python-splines-or-other-interpolations-that-work-with-time-on-x-axis/13941980#comment19225878_13941980

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most numpy/scipy function require the arguments only to be "array_like", [`iterp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) is no exception. Fortunately both Series and DataFrame are "array_like" so we don't need to leave pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(1, 6), [1, 8, 27, np.nan, 125]]).T

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   0    1
0  1    1
1  2    8
2  3   27
3  4  NaN
4  5  125

df2 = df.dropna() # interpolate on the non nan
f = interp1d(df2[0], df2[1], kind='cubic')
#f(4) == array(63.9999999999992)

df[1] = df[0].apply(f)

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   0    1
0  1    1
1  2    8
2  3   27
3  4   64
4  5  125
```

*Note: I couldn't think of an example off the top of my head to pass in a DataFrame into the second argument (`y`)... but this ought to work too.*

Comment: Ahhh.  I see.  How would you do it if your X values in the interp1d function were the dataframe index values?

Comment: You can set `x = df.index` and then `pd.Series(f(x), index=x)`. :)

Comment: OK thanks for your help! and last thing I hope.  I have multiple columns each containing NaN data.  Sol the df.dropna() drops too many rows.  How do you apply that to one column only (i.e. 'data1')

Comment: @user1911866 `.dropna(subset=list_of_cols_to_drop)` (see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html))

Comment: I'm so glad that I came up with the exact same method as hayden suggest: 1. dropna, 2. use x = df.index and 3. create a pd.Series(f(x), index=x). I think I finally see my pandas muscles growing.. ;)

Comment: Thanks again all.  Now I tried that but with the interp1d it gives an error "TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type" which I assume is because the interp1d is being passed x values of datetime and y values as float.  Any ideas on how to use the datetime in the Interp1d function?