# Python splines or other interpolations that work with time on x-axis?

Tags: python, scipy, pandas

Trying to use the awfully useful pandas to deal with data as time series, I am now stumbling over the fact that there do not seem to exist libraries that can directly interpolate (with a spline or similar) over data that has DateTime as an x-axis? I always seem to be forced to convert first to some floating point number, like seconds since 1980 or something like that.

I was trying the following things so far, sorry for the weird formatting, I have this stuff only in the ipython notebook, and I can't copy cells from there:

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline as IUS
type(bb2temp): pandas.core.series.TimeSeries
s = IUS(bb2temp.index.to_pydatetime(), bb2temp, k=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-19c6b8883073> in <module>()
----> 1 s = IUS(bb2temp.index.to_pydatetime(), bb2temp, k=1)

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py in __init__(self, x, y, w, bbox, k)
    335         #_data == x,y,w,xb,xe,k,s,n,t,c,fp,fpint,nrdata,ier
    336         self._data = dfitpack.fpcurf0(x,y,k,w=w,
--> 337                                       xb=bbox[0],xe=bbox[1],s=0)
    338         self._reset_class()
    339 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

By using `bb2temp.index.values` (that look like these:

```
array([1970-01-15 184:00:35.884999, 1970-01-15 184:00:58.668999,
       1970-01-15 184:01:22.989999, 1970-01-15 184:01:45.774000,
       1970-01-15 184:02:10.095000, 1970-01-15 184:02:32.878999,
       1970-01-15 184:02:57.200000, 1970-01-15 184:03:19.984000,
```

) as x-argument, interestingly, the Spline class does create an interpolator, but it still breaks when trying to interpolate/extrapolate to a larger DateTimeIndex (which is my final goal here). Here is how that looks:

```
all_times = divcal.timed.index.levels[2] # part of a MultiIndex

all_times
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2009-07-20 00:00:00.045000, ..., 2009-07-20 00:30:00.018000]
Length: 14063, Freq: None, Timezone: None

s(all_times.values) # applying the above generated interpolator
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-ff11f6d6d7da> in <module>()
----> 1 s(tall.values)

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py in __call__(self, x, nu)
    219 #            return dfitpack.splev(*(self._eval_args+(x,)))
    220 #        return dfitpack.splder(nu=nu,*(self._eval_args+(x,)))
--> 221         return fitpack.splev(x, self._eval_args, der=nu)
    222 
    223     def get_knots(self):

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py in splev(x, tck, der, ext)
    546 
    547         x = myasarray(x)
--> 548         y, ier =_fitpack._spl_(x, der, t, c, k, ext)
    549         if ier == 10:
    550             raise ValueError("Invalid input data")

TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

I tried to use `s(all_times)` and `s(all_times.to_pydatetime())` as well, with the same `TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type`.

Am I, sadly, correct? Did everybody get used to convert times to floating points so much, that nobody thought it's a good idea that these interpolations should work automatically? (I would finally have found a super-useful project to contribute..) Or would you like to prove me wrong and earn some SO points? ;)

Edit: Warning: Check your pandas data for NaNs before you hand it to the interpolation routines. They will not complain about anything but just silently fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that those fitpack routines that are used underneath require floats. So, at some point there has to be a conversion from datetime to floats. This conversion is easy. If `bb2temp.index.values` is your datetime array, just do:

```
In [1]: bb2temp.index.values.astype('d')
Out[1]: 
array([  1.22403588e+12,   1.22405867e+12,   1.22408299e+12,
         1.22410577e+12,   1.22413010e+12,   1.22415288e+12,
         1.22417720e+12,   1.22419998e+12])
```

You just need to pass that to your spline. And to convert the results back to datetime objects, you do `results.astype('datetime64')`.

Comment: I was thinking it must be easy, thanks! But do I assume right that a patch to the high level scipy interpolation routines could just do that for me?

Comment: Sure, a patch would do it. But still seems overkill to me. It could be something simple like `if array.dtype == 'datetime64': array = array.astype('d')`, and then the reverse for the output.

Comment: which is why i'm puzzled that they don't do that anyway.. ;) Why introduce high level classes on top of the fitpack if they don't do work for you? Many of the steps between splrep and InterpolatedUnivariateSpline might have been simple one- or two-liners. In the sum, they count.

Comment: The Scipy code is nearly ten years older than the support for datetimes in Numpy arrays..

Comment: I thought, UnivariateSpline was relatively new, but you are right, at least the Github log even goes back to 2008...