# Down sampling in pandas and spline interpolation

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a hourly time series data in datetime format on x-axis  and pressure on y-axis.

I want to downsample the data to 3-minute intervals and then do a spline interpolation on the y-axis data. I don't know how and if ipython notebook (pandas or numpy) can handle this. I have like 5136 rows of data. Thanks in advance.

```
2015/03/01 00:00:00   100.69
2015/03/01 01:00:00   100.48
2015/03/01 02:00:00   100.30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data are sampled every hour, so when you say "downsample to 3 minutes interval," I think you mean "interpolate [somehow] between the hourly measurements and then evaluate the interpolation at 3-minute intervals." Is this right?

If so, try making your datetime index (or column) into a float like so:

```
import datetime
df['time_as_float'] = df.index.apply(datetime.timestamp())
```

Then start by taking a look at [`scipy.interpolate.splrep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) and its cousin [`.splev`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splev.html) to generate, then evaluate, the splines.

[See also here. (Related SO question).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930367/interpolating-time-series-in-pandas-using-cubic-spline?rq=1)