# Linear 1D interpolation using a interp1D function in Python on panda dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, linear-interpolation

I'm trying to use the "interp1d " function from scipy.interpolate to generate an interpolation from two columns in a python dataframe . I'm using python 2.7. I'm able to generate the interpolation without errors but the interpolation fails to show any reasonable output when the values are supplied within the boundary conditions. For eg  column 'X-Co ordinate' in the 16 columns x 200 rows dataframe DF is between 0.5- 10.5 while the 'Y-Co ordinate' column is a number between range 1.5-99.4. I have generated the interpolation as follows:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import pandas as pd

DF=pd.DataFrame() #This dummy dataframe will have the columns and rows as described above
InterpolatedFunction=interp1d(DF['X-Co ordinate'],DF['Y-Co ordinate'], bound_error=False)
InterpolatedValue_For_X_Equals_5=interp1d(5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interpolating time series in Pandas using Cubic spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930367/interpolating-time-series-in-pandas-using-cubic-spline)

Answer (score -1):

Give the pandas built-in method `df.interpolate(method='linear')` a try.

Comment: Thanks @Yuca, the limitation with the built-in method I see is that the interpolation at random points on the fly couldn't be handled.  For eg. at one point I would be interested in a interpolation for x=5 but then I could also be interested in x=5.123456. This cannot be defined upfront and neednot be at fixed intervals. So looking for a more dynamic approach. Kindly let me know if I'm mis reading the built in method's capability.